# Should I be worried about 3rd-party packages accessing my settings.json?

Tags: meteor

I just saw [a package](https://atmospherejs.com/datariot/ganalytics) that, in order to run properly, asks you to put something in the public section of settings.json. That made me wonder if the rest of the information there (sometimes sensible, like AWS keys) is accessible as well.

So, should I be worried about this or does Meteor hides this information from packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any package you install from any package manager including NPM, Ruby Gems, and the Meteor package server can run arbitrary code on your computer as your user, including using the `fs` module to read and write files, accessing the network to send and receive data, etc.

In fact, you place the same trust in the developer whenever you install an application from the internet - almost any application on your computer could read your `settings.json` file, for example Dropbox, Chrome, etc.

Therefore, there is no way to completely secure the `settings.json` file from package code. The only way to be sure that packages are safe is to use only community-approved packages or read the source code of the packages you are using.